# Node.js MySQL - Retrieve UpdatedId - Insert Into On Duplicate Key

Tags: mysql, database, node.js

I am trying to retrieve the primary key 'id' of my table when I run the query :

```
`INSERT INTO eval (evalTypeId, parentEvalId, authoredContentId) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE evalTypeId = VALUES(evalTypeId), parentEvalId = VALUES(parentEvalId), authoredContentId = VALUES(authoredContentId),[evalObject.evalTypeId, evalObject.parentEvalId, evalObject.authoredContentId]`
```

My schema for the table:

```
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS eval (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  evalTypeId INT NOT NULL,
  parentEvalId INT NULL,
  authoredContentId VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id) ,
  CONSTRAINT fk_eval_evalTypeId
    FOREIGN KEY (evalTypeId)
    REFERENCES .evalType (id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_eval_parentEvalId
    FOREIGN KEY (parentEvalId)
    REFERENCES eval (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE INDEX evalTypeid_idx ON eval (evalTypeId ASC) ;
CREATE INDEX parentEvalId_idx ON eval (parentEvalId ASC) ;
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX authoredContentId_UNIQUE ON eval (authoredContentId ASC) ;`
```

My use case : I have already inserted a record with id = 2 in the table. I want to update the record and fetch the updated row ID. But, in this case, there isn't any update required. I still want to fetch the row ID that is affected.

```
`rows ::  { fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 2,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: '',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }`
```

As shown, my insertId = 0, but I want it to be 2. Is there any way to figure out which ID is being affected during the update process even though there aren't any columns that have to be updated.

P.S - I need to figure this out, as I have to run my updates recursively.